# How to input a string using scanf() and convert it into a character array

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

So im trying to to have a user input a string using scanf() and then convert that string into an array of characters which i can then convert into an array of values depending on the character input.

ive tried inputing a string into an array directly and inputing a string into a variable and then converting that variable into an array

```
int main() {
    char array[100];
    scanf("%s", &array);
}


int main() {
    char input, array[100];
    scanf("%s", &input);
    array[100]=input;
}
```

What i expected was an array of characters which i can access with

```
if(array[6]=='2'){
          ...
}
```

I didnt get any errors but the code under if statements didnt run

Comment: Please read up on the difference of `%c` and `%s` for scanf. E.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf then let us know whether your problem (which is not very clear to me) persists. If yes, please make a [mcve] to demonstrate, naming sample input and describing result. For that your program should be changed to actually have a result, e.g. change to print what was read first, before trying to go all the way. This matches the idea https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/ and also some parts of   https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Also, scanf cannot be used by guessing. Find help here http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: `scanf("%s", &array)` ==> `scanf("%99s", array)` to input a *word* (no spaces) into `array`

Comment: And ALWAYS validate the return, e.g. `if (scanf("%99s", array) != 1) { /* handle error */ }` (or better yet, include `string.h` and use `if (fgets (array, 100, stdin)) { array[strcspn (array, "\n")] = 0; ... }`)

Comment: Note that a string is an array of characters terminated by a null byte.  It isn't clear that you need to split it up after you've read it; it already is in a character array.